# Proguard causes org.hibernate.AnnotationException

Tags: proguard, ejb-3.0, obfuscation, wildfly-10

this is my first time using a obfuscator (ProGuard) for obfuscation of my code. I have two J2EE projects EJB and webProject. Currently I am obfuscating only my EJB.jar project and it is also hosting webservices but before i reach that part i am getting an error

I successfully generated the output jar using ProGuard GUI app, but when I deploy that jar on my server (wildfly) it gave me this exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.metadatatool.b.a
```

This `b.a` is the obfuscated code original names were different.

This exception is basically being invoked on a entity i.e. a View and it has a `@Id` identifier it works normal if I don't obfuscate my code but when I do it gives me this error.
I am using the `-keep attributes` feature of ProGuard but still i am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJB uses reflection and requires that some classes keep their original names, methods and annotations when they go through obfuscation. To fix your problem, you need add a couple of rules such as:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keep @javax.persistence.* class * {
    *;
}
```

to make ProGuard not strip annotations and not touch classes annotated with `@Id`.